# .htaccess rewrite rule stopped working for wordpress site after moving server

Tags: htaccess, rewrite-rules

We have a rewrite rule for categories at archive site in .htaccess file on our server. This is a wordpress site. I am using iTheme Security plugin and at times this plugin meddles with the .htaccess file.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(apple|ball|cat)
RewriteRule ^ http://archive.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Here apple, ball and cat are the categories from old site which we have now on archive.domain.com . So anybody who finds a old link with domain.com/apple/1234 is redirected to archive.domain.com/apple/1234 .

This was working fine. Recently we hosted the same site on another server for 3/4 days and got back to the same server with everything same including .htaccess file where above code lies. And now its not working.

Not sure what changed.

Update: I have noticed another thing which might be issue in blocking the redirects.

domain.com/apple/1234 (if doesn't exist) is going to domain.com/random/1234 if exists. So if I am trying to redirect domain.com/apple/123 to archive.domain.com/123 the redirect is not working because other redirect match is taking over it.

Comment: other redirects from same .htaccess file is working fine.

Comment: Please include the rest of your `.htaccess` file. There is nothing wrong with the directives you've posted, but it's taken out of context. Context is everything when it comes to `.htaccess`.

Comment: sorry, but I do not see anything wordpress specific here

Comment: @MrWhite full htaccess is very very long as various plugins (including w3 total cache etc) has added their own configs. I will try to get the htaccess somewhere and post the link here.

Comment: @mark-kaplun : Sometimes security plugins block some of the htaccess rewrite rules. Since I had no idea why this suddenly stopped working just because we changed server for few days. I had/have doubt that some or the other plugin might be meddling with htaccess. Therefore I posted here in wordpress forum. Thanks.

Comment: and usage of plugins is explicitly off topic here

Answer (score 0):

What is the RewriteBase set to? Is this the first rewrite rule in the .htaccess?

Why are you doing it with a RewriteCond instead of directly going for

```
RewriteRule ^/(apple|ball|cat)(.*) http://archive.domain.com/$1$2 [R=301,L]
```

(Change `^/` to `^` if You have `RewriteBase /` in effect)?

Comment: `RewriteBase` is irrelevant here. `RewriteBase` only affects _relative_ paths in the `RewriteRule` _substitution_ - not the _pattern_. `^/` at the start of the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ would only work if this was used directly in the server config (or virtual host) context. In `.htaccess` you will need to use just `^`.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I've gotten so used to always set `RewriteBase /` and start with ^ without / and haven't actually questioned why. #LearnSomethingEveryday

Comment: (This contrasts with the `REQUEST_URI` server variable, which always starts with a slash.)

Comment: @janh2 this id not work.